# Applescript to copy file from Google Team Drive

Tags: applescript, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to copy a folder on a Google Team Drive to another location, but my script keeps getting an error. The full script is below.

I basically want to copy an Excel file "Google Drive:Team Drives:Company -Sync Folder:0000-1_E.xlsx" to a location that is defined by the script.

The offending line is:

```
duplicate file "Google Drive:Team Drives:Company -Sync Folder:0000-1_E.xlsx" of startup disk to folder (jobNum & " Documents") of newJobFolder
```

Any help?

```
global jobNum
global newJobFolder
set jobNum to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a job number:" default answer "")
set jobName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a job name:" default answer "")
set jobMgr to text returned of (display dialog "Enter account manager email:" default answer "")
set folderpath to (choose folder with prompt "Select client folder")
set newJobFolder to my newFold(jobNum, jobName, folderpath, jobMgr)


on newFold(theNumber, theName, thefolder, jobMgr)
    set emailAddress to jobMgr
    set emailSubject to theNumber & " -" & theName
    set bodyText to ""
    set emailLinkFileName to theNumber & " -" & theName

    set subNameList to {"Designs", "Documents", "Received"}
    set itemCount to count of subNameList
    set linkBody to "mailto:" & emailAddress & "?subject=" & my replace_chars(emailSubject, " ", "%20") & "&body=" & my replace_chars(bodyText, " ", "%20")
    tell application "Finder"
        set newJobFolder to (make new folder at thefolder with properties ¬
            {name:theNumber & " " & theName})
        repeat with i from 1 to itemCount
            set aSubFolder to make new folder at newJobFolder with properties {name:jobNum & " " & item i of subNameList}
            set theMailto to make new internet location file to linkBody at aSubFolder with properties {name:emailLinkFileName, name extension:"mailloc"}
            set the name extension of theMailto to "mailloc"
        end repeat
        duplicate file "Google Drive:Team Drives:Company -Sync Folder:0000-1_E.xlsx" of startup disk to folder (jobNum & " Documents") of newJobFolder
        set name of the result to jobNum & " E.xlsx"
        set theMailto to make new internet location file to linkBody at newJobFolder with properties {name:emailLinkFileName, name extension:"mailloc"}
        set the name extension of theMailto to "mailloc"
    end tell
end newFold

-- Generic find and replace functionality
on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace_chars
```

Comment: And what error message is given ?

Comment: Finder got an error: Can’t set folder "0000 Documents" of folder "0000 test0000" of folder "Desktop" of folder "ace" of folder "Users" of startup disk to file "Team Drives:Company -Sync Folder:0000-1_E.xlsx" of startup disk.

Comment: If, as you said below, your *Google Drive* folder is a mounted drive, then it is not a subfolder of *Startup Disk*.  Try removing `of startup disk` from the problem line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "Google Drive" folder resides directly in your home folder...

Try changing this...

```
duplicate file "Google Drive:Team Drives:Company -Sync Folder:0000-1_E.xlsx" of startup disk to folder (jobNum & " Documents") of newJobFolder
```

To this...

```
set theFile to (path to home folder as text) & "Google Drive:Team Drives:Company -Sync Folder:0000-1_E.xlsx"
duplicate file theFile to folder (jobNum & " Documents") of newJobFolder
```

And if that does not work, You can try this approach...

```
set theFile to (choose file) as alias as text
duplicate file theFile to folder (jobNum & " Documents") of newJobFolder
```

Then after you run it once, comment out the choose file command.

Comment: google drive is a mounted drive so it comes up in devices   We are using the new google file stream so no longer appears as a folder

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Drive File Stream, which is the one for businesses, the mounted drive can be reached through the user folder, the path is something like this:

"/Users/*nameofuser*/Google Drive File Stream/My Drive/*Companyfolder*"

Use this format to get to the folders and it should work, that's what I do.